# How to set up a local test environment for Steem?

Tags: blockchain, decentralized-applications, steemit

I am new to building apps on the Steem blockchain. I want to know how to build a local test environment to test out my app. I dont want to spam the main Steem blockchain with my test transactions.

There are documents on [developers.steem.io](https://developers.steem.io/testnet/index) but those are super confusing.

Any help would be great :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't neccessarily have to run your own. There is at least one public testnet.

```
ChainID: 46d82ab7d8db682eb1959aed0ada039a6d49afa1602491f93dde9cac3e8e6c32
Address prefix: TST
API node: https://testnet.steemitdev.com
```

In JavaScript with steemjs, for example, you could set a flag to point at test during development.

```js
const steem = require('steem');
const test = true;

if (test)
{
    // use a testnet provided by Steemit, Inc.
    steem.api.setOptions({ 
        url: 'https://testnet.steemitdev.com',
        address_prefix:'TST',
        chain_id: '46d82ab7d8db682eb1959aed0ada039a6d49afa1602491f93dde9cac3e8e6c32'
    });
} else
{
    // use the live steem blockchain
    steem.api.setOptions({url: 'https://api.steemit.com'});
}
```